# Linux no space left on device issue

Tags: linux

We have SUSE Linux OS:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Only for a specific file the file creation fails with error no space left on device. We are able to create other files, what has gone wrong?
In the current scenario:

- Inode usage is only 47%

  ```
  $ df -i .
  Filesystem               Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/appvg-dsfs 39321600 18218000 21103600   47% /dsfs
  ```
- Disk usage is only 82%

  ```
  $ df -h .
  Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/appvg-dsfs  591G  457G  105G  82% /dsfs
  ```
- File creation of one specific file fails in this case `JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058`

  ```
  $ echo "a" > JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058
  -bash: JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058: No space left on device
  echo "a" > testfile

  $ mv JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058 tempfile
  mv: cannot stat `JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058': No such file or directory
  ```
- File creation of other files is possible

Comment: Is any SELinux profile enabled?

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but what filesystem are you using? For example XFS has some issues with full partitions, although your disk is not that full.

Comment: What file system is it? (Maybe it is a hardware error? What does dmesg say?)

Comment: Filesystem type is ext3.

Comment: SELinux is disabled

Comment: Can you `echo "a">testfile; mv testfile JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058` (ie, the reverse of the mv above)?

Comment: Could this be a hashing issue as discussed at http://serverfault.com/questions/539536/no-space-left-on-device-error-when-writing-certain-session-filenames ?

Comment: I'd fsck.ext3 it.

Comment: Quotas or AppArmor (similar to SELinux) can also cause this.

Comment: seems an hash-collision issue as described [here][1] http://serverfault.com/questions/539536/no-space-left-on-device-error-when-writing-certain-session-filenames


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/539536/no-space-left-on-device-error-when-writing-certain-session-filenames

Comment: Seems an hash-collision issue as described here: http://serverfault.com/questions/539536/no-space-left-on-device-error-when-writing-certain-session-filenames

Comment: Do you have a vServer or managed Server? The go an check your quotas for this account. You may exceed the disk space granted for the user trying to execute the ```cp```or ```mv``` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you run out of Semaphores. Try this as root

```
ipcs -s
```

and check if there are a lot of semaphores owned by the same user.  If so run the following command

```
ipcs -s |grep username |awk '{print $2}'
```

in the above command replace the username withn the actual user.

Answer (score 0):

really do look like hash-collision issue. Have u tried creating this exact same file in any other empty directory on the same partition to test if it is really hash-collision issue or something else !!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues of this nature when I have mounted a faulty or corrupted drive.  If you have `smartctl` on the host, run it against the device (`smartctl -a /dev/<device>`).  Different drives have different data, but look for things like: `uncorrected errors, multi_zone_error_rate, current_pending_sector,  raw_read_error_rate`, or if it says the drive has failed.  Those are all indicators that the is not in the best state.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly check the size of the file you are trying to create. The file might be very big. Ok I know the chances of the above being the issue may be low, rename the file to a different name or create it with different file name..

Comment: Please read again my question. The file creation command is mentioned there. `echo "a" > JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058` By this method the file size is not over a kb. Even touch gives same error `touch JDE_GL_INCR_STG_201504_181.log.load.058`